# \setlength{\leftskip} affects the "wrapfigure" environment

Tags: wrapfigure

For some reason, I need to indent every paragraph, and so I'm using `\setlength{\leftskip}`.

However, when I use this command, wrapped figures are pushed right as far as the indentation, as shown below.

Is there any solution or an alternative for an indention approach other than `\leftskip`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\leftskip}{2cm}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
\centering
\rule{4cm}{7cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "For some reason, I need to indent every paragraph,": Couldn't you obtain a similar output by changing the left margin using the `geometry` package?

Comment: `\leftskip` is a tex primitive and should never be set directly in latex (it will break most latex display constricts and lists, not just wrapfig)

Comment: Thank you both! I've solved by using the `geometry` package and avoiding using `'leftskip`.